# mac OS X password recovery / using utility/terminal reset no hard drive or user shown

Tags: macos, mac, password-recovery

My password stopped working on my macbook running OS X 10.11. I keep getting diverted to the guest screen.

I searched through stackoverflow and followed the instructions to recover my password through the recovery utility using the terminal. Everything was going as planned except...

Where it says select volume containing the user account there is nothing to select. No volume is showing. So there are also no available users.

Sidenote: I installed ActiveState TCL 8.6 to my mac and restarted it. Problem began after that. Seems like it might be related...

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using FileVault disk encryption. If so, the reset process is a lot different. If not, run Disk Utility and see what it can tell about the disk.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You were correct. It was the FileVault disk encryption. @GordonDavisson

Comment: @TYPOI: If your problem is solved now, please consider answering your own question and marking the solution as "answer". This will help people coming here in the future through a search engine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was extremely idiosyncratic to this specific user’s system and was only solved via a reinstall of OS X so this is not a question that would be useful to many others.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I did fix this problem. I had to unlock my volume by clicking the lock icon (top left on the disk utility) open. That revealed my volume but didn't fix the problem. Tried resetting my password through the disk utility. Which reset my password but also didn't fix the problem. I had to reinstall my os x and use the new password I set. That fixed it.